# How can i wait for a value

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

How can I wait for the value that return from another class?

Main class button

```
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  

                  onPressed: () async {
                    print(selectedYear);

                    selectedYear = await int.tryParse(
                        SetYear(context: context, selectedYear: selectedYear!)
                            .setYear()
                            .toString());
                    print(selectedYear);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month_outlined)),
```

The first print is 2023, but the second is null.
After the second print, the print from the other class "check" is shown
how can I wait until the year is picked from SetYear class?

The SetYear Class

```
class SetYear {
  BuildContext context;
  int selectedYear = 0;

  SetYear({
    required this.context,
    required this.selectedYear,
  });

  Future setYear() async {
    DateTime _selectedDate = DateFormat("yyyy").parse("$selectedYear");
   await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        print("Check");
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Auswahl Jahr"),
          content: Container(
            // Need to use container to add size constraint.
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            child: YearPicker(
              firstDate: DateTime(2021),
              lastDate: DateTime(2050),
              initialDate: DateTime.now(),
              selectedDate: _selectedDate,
              onChanged: (DateTime newYear) {
                if (newYear != _selectedDate) {
                  selectedYear =
                      int.tryParse("${DateFormat("yyyy").format(newYear)}") ??
                          2022;

                  ;
                }

                // close the dialog when year is selected.
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    print("From inside");
    print(selectedYear);
    return Future.value(selectedYear);
  }
}
```

this is the print order

flutter: 2023
flutter: null
flutter: Check
flutter: From inside
flutter: 2022

Answer (score 0):

So, one thing I'm able to find wrong in your code is that you're using await at wrong place.

Below code will fix your issue

```
onPressed: () async {
       print(selectedYear);
       final selected = await SetYear(context: context, selectedYear: selectedYear!).setYear();
       selectedYear = int.tryParse(selected).toString();
           print(selectedYear);
},
```

Comment: Yes... it works as expected, thanks a lot.